# wenzhixin bootstrap-table full screen

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have a wenzhixin bootstrap-table with a toolbar that has the full screen button enabled (data-show-fullscreen="true").

How can I know when the full screen button has been pressed and check if the table is in full screen mode?

Thanks.